# Selenium is not working with firefox and python webdriver on ububtu

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to write test cases for my webapp using selenium, firefox and python webdrivers while my development environment is setup on ubuntu 16.04 LTS but I am getting Exception,

```
WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

**Here is my code block**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
driver.close()
```

**Here is complete exception stack:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LoginLogout.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 99, in _wait_until_connectable
    "The browser appears to have exited "
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

**I have the following environment setup**

> Mozilla Firefox: 47.0
>
> Selenium Version: 2.53.6
>
> python version: 2.7.12
>
> OS: Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP x86_64

Comment: Can you launch Firefox normally outside of the webdriver? Does it happen with the chrome or IE driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is moving away from using FirefoxDriver in favor of [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver). I had this issue a few weeks ago when moving to Firefox 47.0 and made the switch to at that time.

The following [link](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2110) discusses the issue more fully.